# Issues with Gradle for Android -> Android Studio requests to add metadata however it does not work

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-login

I'm struggling to make my app work after i added Facebook login with Firebase. 
I've been having different issues however all of them are about versions and change something in manifest data. The last issue that i got was:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>
> > Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId@value
> >     value=(@string/facebook_app_id) from AndroidManifest.xml:23:13-52     is
> >     also present at [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0]
> >     AndroidManifest.xml:24:13-60 value=(@string/facebook_application_id).
> >       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to 
> >     element at AndroidManifest.xml:22:9-23:54 to override.

I have already tried to change and add the metada tag however it has not worked.

My Gradle file is like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.sosqueen.com.sosqueen"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //General
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'

    // Firebase UI Database
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'

    //Google Play Services
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.0'

    //Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'

    //Facebook Login
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I know that i am using lots of dependencies however i do need them all.

Can anybody help me, please?????

Answer (score 0):

This is better than 
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

```
//Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
```

Visit this page to check the correct Facebook configuration, such as retail keys and so on:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

Comment: Now i got this error -> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.2.0.

Comment: @Calvin That error should be able to be answered using this table https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/README.md#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries